# High and Low bits in van Emde Boas Tree

Tags: data-structures, tree, bit, van-emde-boas-trees

I was trying to understand the concept of vEB tree.

In an example:
I assumed a universe set U = {0, 1, 2, 3 ..... 8}. So the size is 9.

Now lets take a subset S = {0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7}.

For an operation FindSuccessor (3, S); where I need to know the smallest element > 3 in subset S, I need to know the high and low bits of my element i.e. 3.

One explanation says its the first half and second half bits, giving the result 00 and 11 as high and low respectively.

Another says:

high = Floor [element/sqrt(|U|)] = Floor [3/ sqrt (9)] = Floor [1] = 1;

low  = element % sqrt(|U|) = 3 % sqrt (9) = 0;

Please explain where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not going wrong—the explanations are for two slightly different data structures that coincide only when |U| is a square power of two. At a high level, we're trying to divide a key k into two halves, each with about √|U| possibilities. The first method achieves this goal directly; the second is an approximation that runs faster on commodity hardware (assuming |U| is a power of two, the worst case is when |U| is not square and the first half has twice as many possibilities as the second). Pick one method and stick with it.

---

Here's an example of FindSuccessor(3, S). For simplicity, I'm going to bottom out the recursion at three elements.

The tree looks like

```
       min=0|  aux
       max=7|------->min=0|
       / | \         max=2|
      /  |  \         /|\
     /   |   \       0 1 2
    /    |    \
   v     v     v
min=0| min=3| min=6|
max=1| max=4| max=7|
 /|     /|     /|
0 1    3 4    6 7
```

At the root, we split 3 = (1, 0) and check whether the 1th (middle) child has max > 3. It does, so we descend there and use brute force to compute the answer, 4. (Of course, if the tree had more than two levels, we would search recursively.)

A more interesting case is when S = {0, 1, 3, 6, 7}.

```
       min=0|  aux
       max=7|------->min=0|
       / | \         max=2|
      /  |  \         /|\
     /   |   \       0 1 2
    /    |    \
   v     v     v
min=0| min=3| min=6|
max=1| max=3| max=7|
 /|     /      /|
0 1    3      6 7
```

Here, we examine the 1th subtree of the root, {3}, and find that its max is not greater than 3. We find the successor of 1 in the aux data structure, which is 2, and return the min of the 2th subtree, which is 6.

Comment: thanks :)
Can you explain how to get FindSuccessor (3, S) in the above example, using any one of the methods? I am having some troubles understanding the algo behind it.

Comment: @sg1 Okay, added a couple examples.